# Copy LIne in qt shortcut

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

I have been searching a lot on this but of no use. Is there any shortcut to copy an entire line with a keyboard shortcut in QT creator? I have seen shortcut for cutting a line but that's not what i want..

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to mention what kind of widget you are working with (many widgets have "lines", even list boxes)...and what the shortcut you've found for cutting a line is, plus what list of shortcuts you found it in...

Comment: As you've refined your question to Qt Creator (which I don't use), can you explain what "Copy Line Down" and "Copy Line Up" don't do that you want?  The word "line" is only mentioned three times in this list: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_Creator_Keyboard_Shortcuts

Answer (score 13):

The shortcut list is user configurable in `Tools menu -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`.

And the default shortcut to copy a line is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

Set cursor to the line you want copy and press `Command+Alt+Down` or `Command+Alt+Up`
That's it!

You can also move a line:
Mark the line you want to move and press `Command+Shift+Down` or `Command+Shift+Up`

Cheers!

ps: clearly they are shortcuts for mac!

pps: see also https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Creator_Keyboard_Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Alt + Up / Down Arrow on windows